# Remove item from QTreeView without QModelIndex

Tags: qt, qtreeview, qabstractitemmodel, qmodelindex

let's say I decide to randomly remove a few items from my model. I have the references to those items but that's not enough to call the **beginRemoveRows()** method properly. It needs to know the QModelIndex for each item.

But to get the QModelIndex for an item, I need to know the QModelIndex for the parent as well!

```
virtual QModelIndex     index(int row, int column, const QModelIndex & parent = QModelIndex())
```

Only the RootItem doesn't have a parent and therefore doesn't need a QModelIndex. So I would need to start from there and recursively traverse through all children until I end up with the appropriate QModelIndex for each item if this is the correct way of doing things.

Is there a better way to get the QModelIndex for a random item?

Answer (score 0):

Never mind. Apparently I can just use the **createIndex** method to make a QModelIndex for my item.

```
QModelIndex QAbstractItemModel::createIndex(int arow, int acolumn, void *adata) const
```